# execute a certain main depending on what the user decided to do in a graphic interface. JAVA FX

Tags: java, javafx, wait, scenebuilder

I will try to be simple.
In the beginning of the main I create a new Stage which displays 2 button.
Depending on the button clicked, it will set a number to 1 or 2 in the Controller of the stage.
Then I create a condition, if the number is 1 I execute a certain part of the main.
If the number is 2, I execute the other part of the main.

The thing is that I have to wait for the response of the user.I did a while condition(while the number is 0 I come back in the while) but the programs doesn't work.
Do you have an idea to wait for the user's response ?
Here is the beginning of the code.

````
    
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        
        try {
            
            FXMLLoader loader1 = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("SampleStart.fxml"));
            Parent root1 = loader1.load();
            SampleControllerStart StartController = (SampleControllerStart) loader1.getController();
            
            
            
            Scene scene1 = new Scene(root1,474,435);
            primaryStage.setScene(scene1);
            
            
            primaryStage.show();
            
            StartController.setEtat(0);
            

            while(StartController.getEtat() == 0) {
                System.out.println("ok");
            }
            if(StartController.getEtat() == 1) {  ```
````

Comment: You have this entirely structured wrong. The only thing your `start()` method should do is load the FXML and show the stage. Your controller should have an event handler that processes the user response, and then does whatever is needed. I.e. put this logic in the controller, not in the `start()` method.

Comment: It's very bas design. We could possibly help you if we had your FXML and `SampleControllerStart` source (at least the button click handlers)

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you're trying to do is have a dialog with a choice that will condition the rest of your program.

JavaFX is a bit overkill to achieve that, but you could use `javafx.scene.control.Dialog` and get what you're looking for.

Sample:

```java
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {

    ButtonType b1 = new ButtonType("Choice 1", ButtonData.LEFT);
    ButtonType b2 = new ButtonType("Choice 2", ButtonData.RIGHT);
    Dialog<ButtonType> diag = new Dialog<>();
    diag.setTitle("My program");                        //Not required
    DialogPane pane = diag.getDialogPane();
    pane.setHeaderText("You need to make a choice");    //Not required
    pane.setContentText("Choose 1 or 2");
    Circle icon = new Circle(20);                       //should be an image
    icon.setFill(Paint.valueOf("blue"));
    pane.setGraphic(icon);                              //Not required
    pane.getButtonTypes().addAll(b1, b2);
    
    Optional<ButtonType> res = diag.showAndWait();
    if (!res.isPresent())
        return;
    System.out.println(res.get().getText() + " / " + res.get().getButtonData());
    
    if (res.get().equals(b1)) {
        System.out.println("Button 1 clicked");
        //Do something
    } else {
        System.out.println("Button 2 clicked");
        //Do something else
    }
}
```

I'm using `Dialog.showAndWait` here to halt until user makes a choice. Never do a loop like you did without at least a `Thread.sleep()` inside it: this will max out your CPU for nothing, possibly rendering your program not responsive.

Preferably, you would have a full UI made with JavaFX, and handle the user's choices in event handlers for your own controls, and then do your actions in a `javafx.concurrent.Service` that would run it in the background, letting your UI responsive for status display or cancelling your task.

Or you don't really need a UI and use the console to take input from the user...

Comment: Thank you for your help that is exactly what I wanted to do. thanks a million !